# Composer View is not loading variable into view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I created 3 composer views previously and they all work properly, but then I created another one, which doesn't seem to work. I've been trying to get it to work, it doesn't seem to be something related to my code. I will drop a piece of it here, but I still don't think it's the code.

Provider EvenComposerProvider:

```
public function register(){
    $this->composeEven();
}
public function composeEven(){
    view()->composer('includes.aklinkosesi', 'App\Http\Composers\EvenComposer');
}
```

Composer EvenComposer:

```
class EvenComposer{
   public function compose(View $view){
      $view->with('evens', Even::orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(10));
   }
}
```

And than I included the provider inside `app.php`

```
App\Providers\EvenComposerProvider::class
```

When I try to loop through `$evens` with the `foreach`, it throws the error:

> Undefined variable: evens

My rough guess will be that, Laravel does not compile `app.php`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So here is the solutions which might work for people in same sitatuin.
First try these commands:

```
composer update
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear 
composer dumpautoload
php artisan cache:clear
```

I tried a few of them than deleted `bootstrap/cache/config` file and it worked.

Comment: By the way, this goes for anything does not work properly with `Providers` the reason to that is, because Laravel does not compile, clear cache and stuff, each time you run the website. Due to performance it uses old setting.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong, put this code into `boot` method inside of your `provider` and also, remove the code from `register` and remove your method `composeEven`:

```
View::composer(
   'layouts.aklinkosesi', 'App\Http\Composers\EvenComposer'
);
```

Comment: By the way I tried the other one and it worked in 3 other composer but not working with this one

Comment: Can you please vote-up? I might get better chance to have it solved that way

Comment: Ive voted, give us the code for your other composer thats working

Comment: Thanks, it is completely same as it's given for the Even Composer. I literally copied and pasted and than changed unique names. That is why I don't understand why it doesn't work. I tried to do DD($evens) and my provider seem to not even call my composer